# get last 2 days/minutes from mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongodb data like this:

```
"_id" : "sensor-2",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 3,
            "arus" : 0.1
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-05T21:00:19.552+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 8,
            "arus" : 0.1
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-05T21:04:40.594+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 6,
            "arus" : 0.1
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-05T21:05:43.647+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 13,
            "arus" : 0.1
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-04T21:05:45.150+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 15,
            "arus" : 0.05
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-04T21:05:46.651+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 13,
            "arus" : 0.05
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-04T21:05:51.152+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 8,
            "arus" : 0.05
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-04T21:05:52.654+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 11,
            "arus" : 0.05
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-04T21:05:58.756+07:00")
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : {
            "intensitas" : 3,
            "arus" : 0.05
        },
        "tanggal" : ISODate("2018-08-07T21:05:58.757+07:00")
    }
]
```

I want to get the last 2 days or minutes from the array base from id, which "tanggal" is Date in English.

I've tried from this [how to filter last 10 days records from mongoDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712006/how-to-filter-last-10-days-records-from-mongodb?answertab=votes#tab-top) but not what I want because after I get the data I want to average that last 2 days/minutes data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last 2 days you can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
  {
      $unwind: '$data'
  },
  {
    $match: {
      'data.tanggal': {
        $gt: (new Date(new ISODate()-2*1000*60*60*24))
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'data.tanggal': -1
    }
  }
])
```

last 2 minutes you just remove the `24` from the date calc so you get:

`$gt: (new Date(new ISODate()-2*1000*60*60))`

Comment: hy bro, thanks for your answer but when i tray that code (using robomongo) i got "Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms", but if i change "tanggal" to "data.tanggal" i get all data which i've manipulate one of data like ""tanggal" : ISODate("2018-05-05T21:00:19.552+07:00")"  i change the month "05"

Comment: Hi, I had the model wrong without the `data` nesting. Try now.

Comment: Please match the collection name to your `actual collection` name. In other words change `items` to whatever is the name of your collection.

Comment: very well, its work bro in robomongo, but when i implement that on nodeJs, it said "ISODate is not defined". can you get the solution please?? :)

Comment: Well that was your actual question :) You should mark as this being the answer.